# Correct use of the .clear() method on QDateTimeEdit

Tags: python, pyqt

The following script is creating a very simple GUI containing a QDateTimeEdit and a QPushButton only (the script can be run):

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import *

class SmallGUI(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SmallGUI,self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300,300,300,300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Sample')

        #Calendar input
        self.MyInput = QtGui.QDateTimeEdit(self)
        self.MyInput.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.MyInput.setDisplayFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm")
        self.MyInput.setGeometry(88,25,110,20)
        ###############

        #Clear button
        self.MyButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.MyButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(88,65,110,20))
        self.MyButton.setText('Clear date')
        ###############

        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.MyButton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked(bool)"),self.clearDate)

        self.show()

    def clearDate(self):
        self.MyInput.clear()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    sampleForm = SmallGUI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I click the "Clear date" button, however, the method .clear() of the QDateTimeEdit is clearing the first two values only (just the day) and it seems stopping at the "/". I have tried to read some documentations of the object but I couldn't find my way. Does anyone know how I can completely empty the input box when the button is pressed?

Comment: I am very sorry about the formatting of the code but I swear I can't do anything more, I see the correct indenting into the editor but not into the displayed question; for some reason I can't access any functionality of the StackOverflow editor for writing questions, I will have to open a thread on Meta Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the following code?

```
def clearDate(self):
    self.MyInput.findChild(QtGui.QLineEdit).setText('')
```

see http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2009-February/021753.html

Comment: Unfortunately it can't work because the method "setText()" is a method of the QLineEdit but not of the QDateTimeEdit. Hence it will just raise an error :/

Comment: Really? the above code works well in my PC (both python2 and python3). I think that the type of the return value from `findChild(QtGui.QLineEdit)` is not 'QDateTimeEdit' but `QLineEdit`, and invoking the method `setText` does not raise an error.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I have seen you were looking for QLineEdit so I thought you were pointing to the object directly and I've changed to QDateTimeEdit, without thinking you were actually looking for the child of it. Thanks, it works fine!